# Magento collection expression

Tags: magento, collections, expression

How to use expressions in a collection.

More specific, I want to `SELECT CAST(qty_shipped AS UNSIGNED)`.

I have tried something like this:
`addExpressionFieldToSelect('qty_shipped','CAST(qty_shipped AS UNSIGNED)',null)`
, but it appends the table name for some reason.

Thanks.

Comment: FYI, method addExpressionFieldToSelect() won't work with flat models.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try as:

```
$collection->getSelect()->columns(array('qty_shipped' => new Zend_Db_Expr ('CAST(qty_shipped AS UNSIGNED)')));
```

Where $collection = Collection Object

Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Yep, it worked, there was just a typo. Should be "Zend_Db_Expr"
Thanks man.

Comment: Fixed: Zend_Db_Exp -> Zend_Db_Expr. Thanks